# Can be created Firefox addon 'always on top' for inspector?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm web developer on mac os and I need a feature that allow's to pin web inspector in separate window always on top of current page. I'm trying to create addon with this feature, never did it before. Researched developer.mozilla.org but can't find any ability to do it. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Thanks very much for getting involved on Github to get this moving. I think this is a great addon and want to nominate it to get featured. But it needs 2k users first. May you please leave a review for the addon here - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stay-on-top/ - the more reviews it gets, the higher internal ranking it gets on AMO which should get it more traffic. :)

Comment: Yeh, it's great! Hope to see new release in near feature.

Comment: I was thinking when the hotkey is pressed, it should fade in and slide up then fade out an arrow going upwards when it was topped. And when hotkey pressed again it will fade in then slide and then fade out an arrow going downwards. That would be a cool touch.

Comment: Thanks so much for leaving a review! That got the author kick started he merged the PR and released it! :)

Comment: I updated my always on top addon - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/topick/ - you can set any hotkey you want. It works on all system windows on Windows and Linux, on Mac it is just Firefox windows but I hope to find a solution so it is system wide there as well. If you could please leave a rating for me that would be awesome. I'm not getting as many users as "Stay on Top" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use this addon - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/topick/

You can set any hotkey you want. On Windows and Linux it supports toggling "always on top"-ness for all system windows (not just Firefox). On Mac it currently is limited to just Firefox windows, but hopefully soon it will be system wide on Mac as well.

Comment: This addon was removed.

Comment: Anyone else ending up here, dexpot works perfectly on Win11 with Firefox 97. (Also there's a small open source AlwaysOnTop C# program, but I haven't tried it: https://superuser.com/questions/992445/make-any-windowed-application-always-on-top-without-keyboard-shortcut )